# Swift - How to replace view with other View Controller view

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm using `Storyboard` with segue in order to push views into my `NavigationController`.

I have then a `ViewController` where I have added a Segment control for switching 2 views. The segmented control is added in the `ViewDidLoad()`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
  self.view.addSubview(segmentedControl)
}
```

When one of the segment elements is touch I want to change my `ViewController` but don't want to push a new because I want to keep my segmented control.

Any clue?

Comment: I was reading and I guess adding Container View is the way to go. https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/09/02/switch-container-views/

Comment: What does this have to do with view controllers? Just change views. But if you _really_ must use view controllers, then yes, you must follow the rules for child view controllers: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_container_view_controllers

Comment: if model of both the controllers are same then you can just change the datasource.

Comment: view controller with the segmented control and a container view so that when your segmented index change you can change the viewcontroller or your tablevc